# Одинаковый meta description на страницах сайта wordpress

Tags: seo, content, meta

Насколько это плохо для СЕО, если у меня на сайте одинаковое описание в meta description - для главной и для статей?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поле meta description — это ваш шанс повлиять на то, какой текст увидит пользователь под вашей ссылкой в поисковике. Поисковики стараются отображать реальный текст со страницы, поэтому если пользователь ищет что-то конкретное, то разницы мало, будет отображён реальный текст страницы с искомыми пользователем словами. Если же пользователь ищет что-то общее или вообще делает поиск по вашему сайту, то поисковик, обнаружив идентичные описания, будет выбирать текст со страницы на своё усмотрение (или вообще отобразит ваши одинаковые описания). Скорее всего, ваши мысли он не прочитает, поэтому описания будут менее привлекательными, чем если бы вы их написали самостоятельно.